# Selecting all last elements that are not the last sibling

Tags: jquery

I have a structure similar to the following one:

```
<p>
   <span class="top">1</span>
   <span class="top">2</span>
   <span>3</span>
</p>
<p>
   <span class="top">4</span>
   <span class="top">5</span>
</p>
<p>
   <span class="top">6<span>
   <span>7</span>
   <span>8</span>
</p>
```

I want to append something to the last `<span>` of class `top`, but only if it is not the last element in the paragraph. In other words, there should be another `span` without class `top` as a sibling after it.

The result should be that elements 2 and 6 are altered, the other `span`s are either not the last or there are no following items.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$('span.top:last-child').not('span:last-of-type').append('...');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this result with:

```
$("span.top+:not(.top)").prev()
```

"Find `<span>` with class `.top`, then select the following element provided it doesn't have `.top`; retrieve previous sibling of matched elements"

So this won't match 1 or 4 because `+:not(.top)` fails (the next sibling has `.top`). It won't match 5 because there is no next sibling to check for `.top` or not. And it won't match 3, 7, 8 because they don't have `.top` to begin with. Leaving just 2 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("p").each(function() {
    if($(this).find("span.top:last").next().is("span")) {
        $(this).find("span.top:last").append("...");
    }
})
```

Comment: This works, but is not particularly efficient. Aside from the obvious `$(this).find("span.top:last")` being duplicated, it's also worth noting that `:last` is a jQuery extension. Using jQuery extensions in CSS selectors prevents jQuery from using the built-in (therefore significantly faster) `querySelectorAll` from the browser.